# Splitting basic mathematical formulae

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I would like to split `"Hello=World"` into three sections: `"Hello"`, `"="`, and `"World"`. Other mathematical operators like `"<"`, `">="` or `"<>"` might also be used.

Comment: Which language?..Java, C#, Javascript.....?

Comment: I was sure that regex is language independent? It's Ruby.

Comment: What does the operator  `<>` do?

Comment: Might the string be "Hello≠World"? One thing for sure: "like=my bad".

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed '<>' means not equal. I think it's an SQL operator, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"Hello=World".partition(/[=<>]+/)
# => ["Hello", "=", "World"]
```

or

```
"Hello=World".split(/([=<>]+)/)
# => ["Hello", "=", "World"]
```

Comment: Because of the word "like" in the question, perhaps `"Hello=World".partition(/\W+/)` would be more appropriate. Only the OP knows.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.scan` function to match one or more word or non-word characters separately.

```
'Hello=World'.scan(/\w+|\W+/)
# => ["Hello", "=", "World"]
'Hello<=World'.scan(/\w+|\W+/)
# => ["Hello", "<=", "World"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, simple

```
(\w+)(=|<=|>=|>|<|<>)(\w+)
```

To use regex in Ruby, you can use `=~` operator e.g.

```
"Hello=World" =~ /(\w+)(=|<=|>=|>|<|<>)(\w+)/
```

so, you'll get your captured text according to `(...)` via variable `$1`, `$2`, `$3`.

```
$1 = "Hello"
$2 = "="
$3 = "World"
```

Easy right!

In the same way, you also can use it with a `String Partition`.

```
"Hello=World".partition(/=|<=|>=|>|<|<>/)
# which get => ["Hello", "=", "World"]
```

where here you can add more mathematical operators you want `(=|<=|>=|>|<|<>|...)`

see: [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/42uTmggWpO)

Comment: This would not match "Hello>=<World", which is a good thing. You need to show how this would be used (with `partition`, for example). +1

Comment: Oh, I see, you might write `"Hello=World" =~ r; [$1,$2,$3] #=> ["Hello", "=", "World"]`, where `r` is your first regex.

Comment: Thank you for your advice sir, I'm not a rubyist but I found that using regex in `Ruby` is easily done as I use `Bash`, very simple.

Comment: Thank you terces907, this was very detailed and educational :)